# ConcurrentHashMap occur value is null while values().iterator iterating

Tags: java, multithreading

```
 ConcurrentHashMap map=buildMap();//init data
  Iterator<Object> iterator=map.values().iterator();
  while(iterator.hasNext()){
      Objetc data=iterator.next();//(1)
      System.out.println(data);
  }
```

can other Thread do something then make the (1)data is null?if can ,then how to do??

Comment: Are you asking if it can be null, or are you saying that you have actually received a `NullPointerException` on that line?

Comment: I don't understand your question. `data` cannot become `null` once you have a reference to `data` - `ConcurrentHashMap` can't contain `null` values. Of course another `Thread` could remove the mapping from the map after you have retrieved it.

Comment: @BoristheSpider (1) is a marker - see the code comment - not a value.

Comment: @RobinGreen there cannot be an NPE at that line, I think.

Comment: @BoristheSpider yes, while i iterating ,i received a NullPointerException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. `ConcurrentHashMap` does not allow `null` as keys or values.